# User Profile layout in Recyclerview Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

[image]

I don't about this type of `Recyclerview` but I can explain here.
My question is `Recyclerview`list in implements like All profile image layout showing and all profile layout show half view & last profile layout showing full view, but I can't find out this type of any hint in android.

I don't have any code but I have imaged this type of layout implementation.
Attach image layout.

So, Please give me some hint or idea, Thank you.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not recyclerview this is simple view and first 3 images from arraylist is shown in these 3 images and after this there would be shows a plus button when user click on plus button then the full view is opened in recyclerview